# piping pid to kill on ctrl-c

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, process

So I have a Grunt task running this command:

```
java -jar build/lib/plovr.jar serve ./someroot' + configurationFile + ' & grunt watch:sass
```

Problem is, for some reason the java process keeps running when I ctrl-c to the shell.

My idea of solving this would be through piping the pid to a session variable and add another command to kill the same pid.

I have no idea how i can achieve this so i need help. Also, if you can think of a simpler way it will be much appreciated.

Thank you very much

### UPDATE

the problem solved it self when i switched the order of the commands being run, like so

```
grunt watch && java -jar
```

so when i ctrl-c the java process gets killed.

Either way, it would be nice if someone could teach me how to execute my first approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put a & sign on the command line it puts the command preceding it in the background which is why Ctrl-C does not stop it.  To kill it you can either do kill $! where $! is substituted by the shell to the last background submitted task or use the fg command to bring the last task placed into the background to the foreground to which then you can use Ctrl-c.